# How to get the setupBuilder gradle plugin to create a jar launcher in the windows start menu

Tags: java, gradle

I'm struggling to get the gradle setupBuilder plugin to create an installer that adds some sort of launcher (.bat or .exe file?) for my java my app with the nice icon I created for it, to the start menu on Windows10.  It creates an msi that, when run, creates a working jar file just fine.  I thought that setupBuilder had launch4j wrapped inside so that the msi it created would create an exe or something with the icon I gave it and put it in the start menu automatically.  I'm not very familiar at all with Windows, so forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology.  (The creation of a Mac app that goes in the dock with a nice icon was so simple, I figure I must be making a dumb mistake somewhere.)

Here's my build.gradle script:

```
plugins {
  //For building windows exes/msis
  id 'de.inetsoftware.setupbuilder' version "4.5.3c"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'de.inetsoftware.setupbuilder'
apply plugin: 'application'

version = getVersionName()
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  ... <removed for brevity>
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src/main/java/LinkedView/src/'

      ... <removed for brevity>
    }
  }
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class':'edu.stanford.genetics.treeview.app.TreeView3'
  }
  baseName = project.name + '-all'
  from {configurations.compile.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}}
  with jar
}

def getVersionName() {
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
       // might be useful for later version management
       // commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}

//SetupBuilder attempt...
setupBuilder {
    vendor = 'Princeton University Bioinformatics Group'
    application = "TreeView3"
    appIdentifier = "TreeView3"
    description = "Clustering heatmap browser"
    version = '1.0'
    icons = 'src/main/resources/TreeView3.icns'
    licenseFile = 'LICENSES/LICENSE'
    from fatJar.outputs
    bundleJre = 1.7
    mainClass = 'edu.stanford.genetics.treeview.app.TreeView3'
    mainJar = 'TreeView3.jar'
}

msi {

}
```

How do I add a launcher for the jar file (with my icon) to the start menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a desktopStarter block inside the setupBuilder block, however, if you want to specifically do this just for the msi for windows, you can put it inside the msi block like this:

```
msi {
    setupBuilder.desktopStarter {
        displayName = 'TreeView3'
        executable = 'treeview3' + '-all-' + getVersionName() + '.jar'
    }
}
```

The key is to just put your jar file name in the 'executable' variable.  This creates an alias in the start menu with your icon.  However, the icon of the java executable in the taskbar will not be set.  You can accomplish this in your java code in your project with the following in your main JFrame:

```
JFrame appFrame;
appFrame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("TreeView3.png")));
```

I used a PNG.  Theoretically, you should be able to use a .ico file, but when I tried it, it wouldn't work.  (I also tried .icns format.)

After you run the msi, 'TreeView3' with the icon will appear in the start menu and when you run it, the java executable in the taskbar will also have the icon.